# Making a backup file + appending date time + moving file if the file exists. PYTHON

Tags: python, file, datetime, backup, rename

I have a few of the pieces of this working but I'm struggling with putting them together.

I would like to take a file, move it to a backup folder, get the date time from that file, and append it to the file's name / change the file's name to file name + date time.

This part gets the date time in the format I want it. (print line is the date time formatted properly, but I don't need to print this line)

```
    Filepath = "C:\\SyncWork\\ACE\\Files\\ESAL_P\\ESAL_P.txt"
    modifiedTime = os.path.getmtime(Filepath) 
    firstFile = os.path.getmtime(Filepath)

    print (datetime.fromtimestamp(modifiedTime).strftime("%b-%d-%y-%H:%M:%S"))
```

This part will rename / move the file (But it's missing the datetime)

```
    prevName = 'c:\\syncwork\\ace\\files\\ESAL_P\\ESAL_P.txt'
    newName = 'c:\\syncwork\\ace\\files\\ESAL_P\\Backup\\ESAL_P.txt'

    os.rename(prevName, newName)
```

How do I turn the print line with the formatting that I like into a string and append it to the end of the newName line?

**AFTER my question was answered** 
My final code looked like this:

```
Filepath = "C:\\SyncWork\\ACE\\Files\\ESAL_P\\ESAL_P.txt"
modifiedTime = os.path.getmtime(Filepath) 



timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(modifiedTime).strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H.%M.%S")

prevName = 'c:\\SyncWork\\ACE\\Files\\ESAL_P\\ESAL_P.txt'
newName = 'c:\\SyncWork\\ACE\\Files\\ESAL_P\\Backup\\ESAL_P' 

os.rename(prevName, newName+"_"+timestamp + ".txt")
print(newName)
```

Comment: What `strftime` returns is already a string... Perhaps you should review https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: BTW, you can use `os.path.splitext()` on the original file name to split the extension off, which would allow you append the timestamp at the end of root name of the file generically (and not hardcode so many things as you're doing). Also note that the `print(newName)` _isn't_ printing the new generated file name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about splitting the username from the file. I know the print(newName) isn't doing anything. It's actually useless. I only really have it in there to make sure my code is doing anything at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested the following on a file named "temp" which was changed to "temp_Sep-15-14-08:42:57"

```
FilePath = 'temp' # replace the temp with your file path/name
modifiedTime = os.path.getmtime(FilePath) 

timeStamp =  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modifiedTime).strftime("%b-%d-%y-%H:%M:%S")
os.rename(FilePath,FilePath+"_"+timeStamp)
```

Comment: It looks like you got an extra datetime in there. Also, when I put my full path in place of yours it throws an error at me saying: OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\SyncWork\\ACE\\Files\\ESAL_P\\ESAL_P.txt' -> 'C:\\SyncWork\\ACE\\Files\\ESAL_P\\ESAL_P.txt_Sep-09-14-09:44:40'

Comment: @user1837575: The generated file name is invalid because they can't contain colon characters which have a special meaning in Windows. Try something else that's legal like `strftime("%b-%d-%y-%H-%M-%S")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was what was going on. As soon as I removed the colons it worked perfectly. It's strange how it acted with the other iterations I tried, sometimes throwing no errors or weird errors. Anyways, it works now and it's doing exactly what I need it to.

Comment: @user1837575 I haven't dug too far into why but the extra datetime IS required

Comment: @martineau I did this on linux where : are valid

Comment: @sixteenornumber: That's what I assumed (and why I didn't downvote your answer).

Comment: If I add the extra datetime. in there it throws an error. It says type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime But it works just fine with one datetime

Comment: @user1837575 : How are you importing datetime. You can do `python -c "import datetime;print datetime.datetime.now()"` or `python -c "from datetime import datetime;print datetime.now()"`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
timestamp = (datetime.fromtimestamp(modifiedTime).strftime("%b-%d-%y-%H:%M:%S"))
newName = 'c:\\syncwork\\ace\\files\\ESAL_P\\Backup\\ESAL_P.txt.' + timestamp
```

Comment: This puts the timestamp *after* the file's extension!

Comment: Yep - that's what was asked for.  Don't vote me down for following the letter of the spec!

Comment: This SEEMS like what I'm looking for but it doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error either, but I get no file in my backup folder. I can't seem to figure out why. Also, I'd rather not append the date time after the file extension, rather concatenate the date time to the end of the name of the file. 

I got a print(newName) at the end of the script and it returns basically what I'm looking for, but the file doesn't move to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the solution that you already have to avoid duplication of code and add usability, I would suggest using the `path` library:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# create the filename as a path
filename = Path("C:\\SyncWork\\ACE\\Files\\ESAL_P\\ESAL_P.txt")

# derive the name of the backup folder from the origin and create it if necessary
target_directory = filename.parent / 'Backup'
if not target_directory.is_dir():
    print(f'Creating directory {target_directory}')
    os.mkdir(target_directory)

# this is the original part creating the timestamp
modified_time = os.path.getmtime(filename)
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(modified_time).strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H.%M.%S")

# build the target name from the original name, the timestamp and the original extension
target_file = target_directory / f'{filename.stem}_{timestamp}{filename.suffix}'
print(target_file)
os.rename(filename, target_file)
```

This approach has the advantage of working for any extension and being safer. It looks longer, but if you strip out the comments it becomes just the same length as yours:

```
filename = Path("C:\\SyncWork\\ACE\\Files\\ESAL_P\\ESAL_P.txt")
target_directory = filename.parent / 'Backup'

modified_time = os.path.getmtime(filename)
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(modified_time).strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H.%M.%S")

target_file = target_directory / f'{filename.stem}_{timestamp}{filename.suffix}'
print(target_file)
os.rename(filename, target_file)
```

I hope you find it useful.