# Save a file name as "date - backup"

Tags: python, datetime

I am currently exporting a table from by Bigquery to G.C.S as another form of a backup. This is the code I have so far that saves the file name as "firebase_connectioninfo.csv".

```
# Export table to GCS as a CSV

data = 'dataworks-356fa'
destination = 'gs://firebase_results/firebase_backups1/Firebase_ConnectionInfo.csv'

def export_data_to_gcs(data, Firebase_ConnectionInfo, destination):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(data)
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('FirebaseArchive')
    table = dataset.table('Firebase_ConnectionInfo')
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.extract_table_to_storage(
        job_name, table, 'gs://firebase_results/firebase_backups1/Firebase_ConnectionInfo.csv')
    job.source_format = 'CSV'

    job.begin()

    wait_for_job(job)

def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)

export_data_to_gcs(data, 'Firebase_ConnectionInfo', destination)
```

I want this file to be named as "thedate_firebase_connectioninfo_backup". How do I add this command in a Python script?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the current date to the filename? You'd use the `datetime` module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Yes thats whats I mean. Would I just put datetime.date + firebase_connecitoninfo?

Comment: I'll provide an answer with an explanation of the steps.

Comment: it might be duplicated as this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851314/making-a-backup-file-appending-date-time-moving-file-if-the-file-exists-pyt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import datetime

datestr = datetime.date.today().strftime("%B-%d-%Y")
destination = 'gs://firebase_results/firebase_backups1/' + datestr + '_Firebase_ConnectionInfo.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is your string:

```
gs://firebase_results/firebase_backups1/Firebase_ConnectionInfo.csv'
```

What I would suggest is putting it into its own variable:

```
filename = 'gs://firebase_results/firebase_backups1/Firebase_ConnectionInfo.csv'
```

Additionally, we should put in a spot for the date. We can handle formatting the string a couple different ways, but this is my preferred method:

```
filename = 'gs://firebase_results/firebase_backups1/{date}-Firebase_ConnectionInfo.csv'
```

We can then call `format()` on the `filename` with the date like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now().strftime("%M-%D-%Y")
filename.format(date=date)
```

Another way we could format the string would be the old string formatting style with `%`. I hate this method, but some people like it. I think it *may* be faster.

```
date = datetime.now().strftime("%M-%D-%Y")
filename = 'gs://firebase_results/firebase_backups1/%s-Firebase_ConnectionInfo.csv' % date
```

Or, you could use the other guy's answer and just add the strings like

```
"This " + "is " + "a " + "string." 
outputs: "This is a string."
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ilya. I should really proofread my posts before I post them...